# Increase Count for Conditional Values in Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that I am using Python 3.7 and Pandas on and I am strugging with counting rows. Based on the simplified version below, I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I need to interate over to get a count.

```
A          B    
WalMart  "Yes"
Target
WalMart  "Yes"
BestBuy
Target   "Yes"
```

What I am trying to make work is below:

```
A          B     C
Gap              0
WalMart  "Yes"   1
Target           1
WalMart  "Yes"   2
BestBuy          2
Target   "Yes"   3
```

Code Attempt:

```
initial_count = 0
if (df["B"]=="Yes"):
   df["C"]= initial_count+1
```

I have a count that starts at zero, and every time column B contains a "Yes", add to this count. Any thoughts on how I can do this? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare value and use cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['new'] = (df["B"]=="Yes").cumsum()
print (df)
         A    B  new
0  WalMart  Yes    1
1   Target  NaN    1
2  WalMart  Yes    2
3  BestBuy  NaN    2
4   Target  Yes    3
```

With some rows before first `Yes`:

```
df['new'] = (df["B"]=="Yes").cumsum()
print (df)
         A    B  new
0      gap  NaN    0
1  WalMart  Yes    1
2   Target  NaN    1
3  WalMart  Yes    2
4  BestBuy  NaN    2
5   Target  Yes    3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know cumsum() existed. That saves a ton of time!